# Jira API Assignee not populating with "name" anymore, instead needs "accoundId"

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, jira

I'm working with Python 3.x

Previously, I had a function to create tickets that looks like this

```
def jira_incident(jira_subject, jira_description):
    user = "username"
    apikey = 'apikey'
    server = 'https://serverName.atlassian.net'
    options = {
        'server': server,
        'verify': False
    }
    issue_dict = {
        'project': {'key': 'project_name'},
        'summary': str(jira_subject),
        'description': str(jira_description),
        'issuetype': {'name': 'Incident'},
        'assignee': {'name': my_username},
        'priority': {'name': 'Low'},
        'customfield_10125':
            {'value': 'Application Ops'}
    }
    jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(user, apikey))
    new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
    return new_issue
```

my_username is a global variable that's used for other things as well.

Anyway, the assignee is no longer working as of about 2 days ago. I did some googling and found that it now needs the accountId instead of the name, I can get this via the web UI by leaving a comment as @'ing someone in a comment. As a temporary solution I've populated a dictionary to reference (and that works), however I'd like to make this more dynamic for future proofing the script.

```
'assignee': {'accountId': jira_dict[my_username]},
```

I can't seem to really find any documentation on looking up the accountId from the name, and I figured I'd go ahead and ask the community to see if anyone else has run into/solved this issue.

I was thinking about just writing a new function that performs this query for me, then returns the accountId.

**EDIT**
I did find this:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

url = "/rest/api/3/user/bulk/migration"

auth = HTTPBasicAuth("email@example.com", "<api_token>")

headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   headers=headers,
   auth=auth
)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```

However it 404's on me, I add the server address to the beginning of the url, and replace user, with the username in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution, it's not an elegant solution, but it does exactly what I need it to. So here is the new function:

```
def jira_account_id_from_username(username):
    r = requests.get('https://serverName.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/user?username=' + username, auth=("username",api_key), verify=False)
    value = re.search('"accountId":"(.*?)",', str(r.text)).group(1)
    return value
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly encourage you to not rely on the `username` anymore. The endpoint you are using is deprecated, see also https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-user-privacy-api-migration-guide/.

The "new" or probably better way is to use the `/user/search` endpoint as described here: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-rest-api-3-user-search-get There you can define a `query` that is matching against certain properties of a user (`displayName` or `emailAddress`), or search for the `accountId` if you already have it. Therefore, if you are linking users from the cloud to some other "user directory" (or just a scripts where you have stored some usernames), replace it by using either email address or accountId so you can properly link your users.

Comment: `url = "https://server.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/user/search"`  
`auth = HTTPBasicAuth(email_address, api_key)`  
`query = {`  
`   'username': username,`  
`    'emailAddress': emailaddress`  
`}`  
`response = requests.request(`  
`   "GET",`  
`   url,`  
`   params=query,`  
`   auth=auth`  
`)`  
`value = re.search('"accountId":"(.*?)",', str(response.text)).group(1)`  
This returns the same value as what I posted above, but using the info from your second link, does that look about right? I don't like the idea of splitting a str to get what I want though.